# iphone application paypal payment integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, paypal

I want to add paypal payment to my iphone application what is the best way of doing it? will apple approve the app if the payment transaction will be done within application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to integrate Paypal with the iOS application i.e. 
1) MPL - Mobile payments library : Launces Paypal window on the top of application window.
2) MECL - Mobile express checkout library : Launces in a webview

You can use MECL to implement paypal.
For dev purpose, they have provided with sandbox inputs to be used. Once you develop the app, you need to submit it to paypal. Paypal will verify and test your application for various payment scenarios and security as well. Once they approve, they(Paypal) will provide you with a production env id number. USe that number in the app and upload it to app store.

Apple uses In app purchase to sell digital goods. So it does not allow to use any other payment gateway for selling digital content.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has provided an SDK for iOS. Simple [Google](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=hi&site=&q=paypal%20ios%20sdk&oq=paypal%20ios%20sdk&aq=f&aqi=g-L1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1274l7544l0l7882l28l23l5l6l5l0l244l1812l2.8.2l12l0) should have got you [this](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk).

And as far your other question is concerned. This statement should clarify things:

> Hello, Apple policy restricts from using our library for accepting digital goods. Use our library should be for hard goods, donations, personal payments and services only.

Comment: That page doesn't show any iOs SDK. Did it disappear or am I missing something?

Comment: What about e-tickets?